# rasterio crs returns None while it has crs in ArcMap

Tags: python, conda, gdal, rasterio, epsg

I clipped a raster in ArcMap, reprojected it to wgs84 and exported it as tiff file. Then I read this raster using rasterio and the .crs returns 'None', but I am expecting it to return the corresponding epsg value. [This](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/1832) seems relevant, I tried activating the environment but of no use. I do not understand "GDAL_DATA or PROJ_LIB environment variable pointing to an invalid location". What does this mean? What might be the reason to get 'None' crs?

Comment: Just a pointer: This is due to GDAL versions which are too old for rasterio. How projections are saved in GDAL has been changed in the last few years